# python how to remove substring by index

Tags: python, string

i have a string in a loop ,but everytime a specific part needs to be replaced

```
url = 'google.com.'
rest = '.720p.SS.mkv'
for i in range(10, 17):
    rest = str(i) + rest
    final = url + rest
    print(final)
    rest[:2] = '' # TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

i need this loop to print :

```
google.com.10.720p.SS.mkv 
google.com.11.720p.SS.mkv
google.com.12.720p.SS.mkv
...
```

should i use replace() for it?

Comment: @user136952 He's not looping over a list

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replace? It looks like you're just concatenating the `url`, `i` and `rest`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a great use case for **[f-string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)**:

```
url = 'google.com.'
rest = '.720p.SS.mkv'
for i in range(9, 17):
    final = f'{url}{i:02d}{rest}'
    print(final)
```

**Output:**

```
google.com.09.720p.SS.mkv
google.com.10.720p.SS.mkv
google.com.11.720p.SS.mkv
google.com.12.720p.SS.mkv
google.com.13.720p.SS.mkv
google.com.14.720p.SS.mkv
google.com.15.720p.SS.mkv
google.com.16.720p.SS.mkv
```

Comment: thank but how about if i want variable i starts from 1 ... but in the final string prints as 01 , 02 , ... , 09,10,11.
something like %02d i suppose?!

Comment: @Pouria Use `{i:02d}` in the f-string.

Comment: @Pouria Was afk as Barmar said. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't reassign the original variables. Just concatenate all the strings and assign that to `final`.

```
for i in range(10, 17):
    final = url + "%02d"%i + rest
    print(final)
```

Comment: thank but how about if i want variable i starts from 1 ... but in the final string prints as 01 , 02 , ... , 09,10,11. something like %02d i suppose?!